# Python multiprocessing for processes which are started separately

Tags: python, queue

Is ist possible somehow to use queues for proceses which are started comopletely separately (e.g. from command shell). In such cases multiprocessing package doesn't word, because the new process must be passed the queue in advance.

Comment: Check http://python-rq.org/ for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://python-rq.org/ is your simplest option - considering you have or install Redis.